# Call a function written inside of __init__ somewhere else in the Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, init

So say I have a Class:

```
class Testclass:
      def __init__(self, key)
          self.key = key


          def function(self, key):
              do something ...
```

can I call specifically the `function` without calling the whole `__init__` somewhere down the line inside a Testclass Method?

I need this because I have two functions within `__init__` and I need them separately.

Or maybe I am doing this all wrong from the get go, so any other suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: You cant. Its a function scoped function and only available inside it. If you need them outside, declare them as member functions of the class.

Comment: @Torxed well I tried and got AttributeError that there is no attribute "function"
my original issue is that I need to have a random list in Max-Heap state after initialisation so I wrote heapify and buildHeap functions inside __init__ but I need to call them later in a HeapSort Method. 
and yea it an assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot, because those functions are local to `__init__`. Why don't you make them methods of the class?

```
class Testclass:
  def __init__(self, key)
      self.key = key
      result = self.function(key)

  def function(self, key):
      do something ...
```

Comment: see my comment above why I can not write as Methods. I need something achieved right in the __init__

Comment: @Leonardo you can call that function from within init (see my edit)

Comment: that was my first instinct and I tried it, but I was getting the error that function is not defined or something along those lines, I may have made syntax errors though... let me try that again.

Comment: yep that worked, I must have messed up something with self's before... I just started OOP... TY

Comment: @Leonardo no worries! Have fun :)

Comment: Am I stupid if I bring up the fact that you can create non-instance-classes? `class TestClass: def function(key): ...` and access it with `TestClass.function()` without an instance?